# XPages and xe:jdbcQuery - dynamic queries

Tags: jdbc, xpages

Before I ask my question I clarify that I aware of xe:sqlParameter option.

**The question:** how can I implement possibility to prepare queries dynamically based on user input on the page?

Example scenario: SQL table "datatable1" with data also has columns "type" and "color". I am showing all content from the table by using the following code:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xe:jdbcQuery var="dataDS" connectionName="dataConnection">
        <xe:this.sqlQuery><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM datatable1]]></xe:this.sqlQuery>
    </xe:jdbcQuery>
</xp:this.data>
```

Data table content itself displayed by xe:dataView.

So, basically the question, is it possible to cover with single datasource xe:jdbcQuery and single page all cases listed below:

**Case 1:** End-user sees all records (this is covered by code above);

**Case 2:** End-user would like to see all records where color = "red"

> For this case I would use query: "SELECT * FROM datatable1 WHERE color = ?" and pass value for parametr via xe:sqlParameter. But this brakes possibility to view all records, as I can not pass value with meaning "any". Or it possible?

**Case 3:** End-user would like to see all records where type = "car"

> Very similar to Case 2.

**Case 4:** End-user would like to see all records where color = "red" and type = "car"

> For this case I would use query: "SELECT * FROM datatable1 WHERE color = ? AND type = ?" and pass value for parametrs via xe:sqlParameter.

At this moment I do not see solution for my question... Of course I can do lookups in SQL DB dynamically in ManagedBean, but then I lost sorting and presentation functionality of  xe:dataView and would have to do it manually, let say by repeat or xp:dataTable, what I would like to avoid...

Thank you in advance for your posts!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Like operator and substitute % for cases where you want everything to match. You have to use the SQL parameters in the data source. Compute that to return the desired value or if empty/null return %.

SELECT * FROM datatable1 WHERE color LIKE ? AND type LIKE ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I was not able to get it working properly... So in case I would like to have prepared statement, and to show all records, the result (computed) formula should be [SELECT * FROM datatable1 WHERE color LIKE % AND type LIKE %]? Could you please correct me if I wrong? FYI: I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: You need a single quote around the % as in SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '%' and ContactName LIKE '%';

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp and try the Try It Yourself buttons and then you can add your own sql to experiment.

Comment: thank you for guidelines! Yep, surrounding % with single quote works. I thought I tried it, do not understand what was wrong that time. Also, I noticed that using LIKE operator returns not all records, I think it is because of empty values... I will note such realization for future as currently finalizing this functionality with help of SessionMap. I use SessionMap very careful and actually use it only to pass prepared query between page reloads by getting prepared query from sessionScope by .remove(). So it will not garbage sessionScope but this realization I already loved. ))

Answer (score 1):

We developped an application that searches for postal addresses.  The end user enters some informtation, like street name and city, OR enters a zip code, and we build a SQL string according to what has been entered.  Then, that SQL Query is put in a session scope variable that is used by the view to get the data it displays.  The session scope SQL query is initialized to "Select * from our_table".  The key here is the view using the JDBC Query data source, bound to the session scope variable.

Here is the data section of the xp:viewpanel

```
<xp:this.data>
   <xe:jdbcQuery var="view1" connectionName="oracle" calculateCount="true" sqlQuery="#{javascript:sessionScope.SQLQuery;}"></xe:jdbcQuery>
</xp:this.data>
```

Comment: Yep, I also noticed that sqlQuery in xe:jdbcQuery computed only once on page load. So sessionScope I left as workaround for last case... Obviously, currently - it is only one possible way to implement it in the way I need. Already did feasibility - works fine. Will post my code after I finalize it.